# How to view/delete read-only contacts with Google contact

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I have 550 contacts. 450 have Google account, and 100 are read-only contacts.

I want to clean up my phonebook. So I want to do one of these:

1. Delete all 100 read-only accounts with no Google account in bulk.
2. See a list of 100 read-only contacts that don't have any Google account.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 apps installed, both of them will do this job.

1. Contacts Optimizer. This runs on the phone and will allow you to see these contacts and edit, delete, merge them.
2. My Phone Explorer. The client runs on the phone and a companion app runs on Windows. The data is dynamically pulled into Windows, where you can individually alter the contacts.

Please note, I am not associated with either.